# Entire functions of order zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across this question:

If $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function of order zero then $f$ is a polynomial?

Note that the converse is true.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true. We just need that the Taylor coefficients of $f(z)$ in a neighbourhood of zero decay *very fast*:
$$ f(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-n^2}z^n $$
is an example of an order-$0$ entire function.

Comment: Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_0.